# Access Denied (Status 403) error message trying to access index.html file declared in Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on a `Spring Boot` project using `Spring Security` and I have the following problem trying to allow access to a test `index.html` page declared inside my project.

Basically I have the following situation. Into my project I have this folder: `src/main/resources/static` folder containing the `index.html` file.

The `Spring Boot` `Tomcat` server run on the `8019` port, in-fact this is the start-up log:

```
[2m2022-02-17 17:04:06.882[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16062[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 8019 (http) with context path ''
```

So I try to run this `index.html` file in my browser opening this URL: `http://localhost:8019/index.html`

But I am obtaining this error message:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Feb 17 17:03:54 CET 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Access Denied
```

I also tried to add a `permitAll()` rule into my `Spring Security` configuration class, this one:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtConfig jwtConfig;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    
    //private static final String[] USER_MATCHER = { "/api/utenti/cerca/**"};
    //private static final String[] ADMIN_MATCHER = { "/api/utenti/inserisci/**", "/api/utenti/elimina/**" };
    
    private static final String[] USER_MATCHER = { "/api/users/email/**"};
    private static final String[] ADMIN_MATCHER = { 
                                                        "/api/users/email/**",
                                                        "/api/admin/**"
                                                   };

    private static final String[] COMMON_MATCHER = {
            "/api/admin/user/{id}/wallet"
    };
    
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception 
    {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }   
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        /*
         * NOTE:
         * Using hasRole expects the authority names to start with 'ROLE_' prefix
         * Instead, we use hasAuthority as we can use the names as it is
         */
        http.csrf().disable()
                   .authorizeRequests()
                   .antMatchers(USER_MATCHER).hasAnyAuthority("CLIENT")
                    .antMatchers(COMMON_MATCHER).hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","CLIENT")
                   .antMatchers(ADMIN_MATCHER).hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
                   .antMatchers("/api/users/test").authenticated()
                   .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "http://localhost:8019/index.html").permitAll()
                   .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, jwtConfig.getUri()).permitAll()
                   .anyRequest().denyAll()
                   .and()
                   .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(
            new TokenVerificationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtConfig, jwtTokenUtil),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
    
    /* To allow Pre-flight [OPTIONS] request from browser */
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) 
    {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**",
                                    "/webjars/**",
                                    "/v2/**",
                                    "/swagger-resources/**",
                                    "/swagger-ui.html");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    };


}
```

So as you can see I added this configuration line:

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, jwtConfig.getUri()).permitAll()
```

But it is not working and I still not access to this URL and to the page contained into my `index.html` file.

Disabling Spring Security it works fine so the problem must be in the Spring Security configuration

Answer (score 0):

I see two things in your configuration that could be causing this.  First, you're adding a custom filter, if that filter sets a 403 on the response then the rest of the configuration won't apply, so check the `doFilter` method in `TokenVerificationFilter`.

The other culprit could be in your matcher, in which you've included not only the path, but also the protocol, host, and port.  Limit this matcher to just `/index.html` and you should be set.

Also, to throw another solution your way...  You've already got an ignoring section in your `public void configure(WebSecurity web)` method, just add `/index.html` to your list of ignores, that's effectively what you're trying to do anyway :)